# weblogic.management.ManagementException: There is the same running task.

Tags: hibernate, deployment, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an ear file into Weblogic 12.c application server. I was able to deploy it successfully, but the last time, it got the connection to the database.

After that it keeps giving me this exception and the ear does not deploy any more.

**The deployment has not been installed.
weblogic.management.ManagementException: There is the same running task. New Task: (deploy for my-package), Running Task: (deploy for my-package)**

This happens even after I have restarted my server and did a clean deploy.

Please help.

Thanks
gmk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because weblogic adminserver was holding a lock on the deploy task. Restart the AdminServer and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to restart, you can delete a failed deployment from the Weblogic console, activate all the changes, and retry the deployment.